# Angular [ngClass] inside *ngFor for selected item

Tags: angular

> Hi,i need some help to set [ngClass] to clicked item. I have class in css file. I need this style stay on selected item even when component is destroyed. What i have does not work. sccdoes not apply to clicked item.

```
 <ul *ngFor="let item of list$ | async" [ngClass]="{ selected: selectedSong === item }">
    <li><h5><a (click)="sentItem(item.ID)">{{ item.name }}</a></h5></li>
    <li>{{ item.description }}</li>
 </ul>
```

```
selecedSong:any;
```

```
  sentItem(ID: string) {
    this.musicService.setViewed(ID);
    this.selectedSong = ID;
    this.router.navigate(["/some-route",ID]);
  }
```

Comment: can you please give some code snippet in stackbliz

Comment: I noticed that when page renders i have this cde in ui: ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]".   If i add css class  manually in Elements- it works. Is the problem with css not being applied?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with this solution? In your html file replace condition with **`[ngClass]="{ 'selected': selectedSong === item.ID}"`** this condition.

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of list$ | async" [ngClass]="{ 'selected': selectedSong === item.ID }">
  <li>
    <h5><a (click)="sentItem(item.ID)">{{ item.name }}</a></h5>
  </li>
  <li>{{ item.description }}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks, but it did not make  any difference.

Comment: Are you replace the condition in html?

Comment: New Condition is [ngClass]="{'selected': selectedSong === item.ID}".

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with this? In your html file replace condition with double equal sign(==) instead of ===
just in case if value are not matching with type.

**[ngClass]="{ 'selected': selectedSong == item.ID }">**

Answer (score 0):

Here you need some design changes, first change ngClass condition like below

```
 [ngClass]="{ 'selected': selectedSong === item.ID }"
```

another thing is you are just initializing the **`selectedSong`** but assigning any value so, there no chance that above condition getting true.

you are assigning value in click method but it's navigating immediately after that..

if you want see the difference you can observe this by setting value to *selectedSong*, might be first element of the ***items***.

Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

We can fix your problem in 2 way.

First Solution:

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of list$ | async" [ngClass]="{ selected: selectedSong === item }">
    <li><h5><a (click)="sentItem(item)">{{ item.name }}</a></h5></li>
        <li>{{ item.description }}</li>
 </ul>
sentItem(item) {
    this.musicService.setViewed(item.ID);
        this.selectedSong = item;
        this.router.navigate(["/some-route",item.ID]);
}
```

Second Solution:

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of list$ | async" [ngClass]="{ selected: selectedSong === item.ID }">
    <li><h5><a (click)="sentItem(item.ID)">{{ item.name }}</a></h5></li>
        <li>{{ item.description }}</li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, but none of those works. The problem is in here:  this.selectedSong = item;  selectedSong is a boolean and  somehow  it has to be === ID ,  not item- as item  is not accessible from this component. ID is.